# Do you need to HTML encode Title tags?

Tags: html

Should you HTMLencode Title tags in the head section of an HTML page?

eg `<title>This & That</title>`

or `<title>This &amp; That</title>`

Comment: Please rephrase, this doesn't really make any sense to me.  If you're asking if the <title> tag should be included in <head> then yes since that is where it is supposed to live.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you should use `&amp;` instead of `&` inside your `<title>` tag, same with any other tag in your HTML or XML document.

Comment: Thanks. Yes good reasoning. I will accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: Does this hold generally, or only for a subset of encodable characters?

Comment: It's a pity that many applications that make use of this tag don't bother to URL-decode it first.